# COUNTIF formula with limited maximum output

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I have a simple `COUNTIF` formula that counts the number of times a person's name appears in a range of cells and then multiplies it by 8. However, I would like to add the second criteria: if the count is > 5, then count = 5.

Help very much appreciated.

- in this example cell (`AH$3`) is the person's name.

```
=COUNTIF(X1036:AA1077,AH$3)*8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
=MIN(COUNTIF(X1036:AA1077,AH$3),5)*8
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This would set 5 as a minimum, correct? What if count < 5? Here is the full formula, as I am adding two formulas and getting rather confused how to write it. ```=SUM(AH1036:AH1077)+(COUNTIF($X1036:$AA1077,AH$3)*8)```

Comment: @Craig, this would set 5 as the maximum funny enough =). When count is larger than 5 it will always be 5. When count is smaller than 5, count will be count. As we don't know exact what you want to achieve I could only advise you. So maybe you looking for `=SUM(AH1036:AH1077)+(MIN(COUNTIF($X1036:$AA1077,AH$3),5)*8)`.

Answer (score 1):

In according to using the "min" function, you could also create another if statement - although this doesn't look as nice:

```
IF(CalcResult>5;5;CalcResult)

=IF(COUNTIF(X1036:AA1077,AH$3)*8)>5;5;COUNTIF(X1036:AA1077,AH$3)*8)
```

Note: it doesn't really make a difference here, but you might want to consider using ">=" instead of ">".

Comment: Solved! Thanks so much.